# Oracle: Display the max description in courses

Tags: sql, oracle, aggregate-functions

I am writing the query that will return the courses with the longest description. Here, what am I thinking but it wont work?

```
SELECT Max(DESCRIPTION) 
FROM course
```

Comment: a `WHERE` clause?

Answer (score 0):

This will give you the maximum description of course table.

```
select description
from (select description, length(description) as len
from course 
order by len desc) t
where rownum = 1
```

Comment: I don't need a length. I need a largest description in my description column.

Comment: How will this handle ties, that is, two or more descriptions tied for longest?

Answer (score 0):

Inner query to select maximum description length and outer query to list courses which have that maximum length.

```
select * from course 
where length(description) = (select max(length(description)) from course);
```

If you just want the description, use `select description from ...` instead of `*`

Comment: I need a  longest description in my description column. For example "Java for C/C++ Programmers"

Comment: Yes, if you use select description from instead of select * in my query you should get it

Comment: The solution is correct. However, if performance is important, one may prefer to use the analytic function solution. The aggregate subquery in this solution requires the base table to be read twice.

Comment: @mathguy Agree. But I'd presume a _course_ table isn't that big.

Comment: I agree. But good habits must be developed early, otherwise in many cases they don’t develop at all.

Answer (score 0):

Use analytic `max()` function in a subquery. That way the base table is read just one time.

```
select description
from   ( 
         select description, length(description) as len,
                max(length(description)) over () as max_len
         from   course
       )
where  len = max_len
;
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use `length comparison` by using `outer join` and include `ties` for`course descriptions` :

```
create table course
(
  course_id int,
  description varchar2(100)
);     
insert all 
  into course(course_id,description) values (1,'Mathematics')
  into course(course_id,description) values (2,'Physics')
  into course(course_id,description) values (3,'Mathematics')
  into course(course_id,description) values (4,'Biology')
  into course(course_id,description) values (5,'Chemistry')
select * from dual;    
select c1.course_id, c1.description 
  from course c1  left outer join 
       course c2 on length(c2.description) > length(c1.description)
 where length(c2.description) is null;

COURSE_ID      DESCRIPTION
-----------    --------------
1              Mathematics
3              Mathematics
```

[Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/12060/1)